# Is there a way to force Windows "Browse For Folder" to jump to an address?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, file-management

I'm talking about this standard Windows file select window that some programs create:
[image: "Browse For Folder" standard Windows file select window]

It is quite annoying having to navigate throughout the whole filesystem to the folder you want, every time you have to use this window. Is there some way to "inject" an address or replace this box with one that at least has a address bar or something equally useful? Thanks

EDIT: I suppose I should exclude AutoHotKey (or similar) scripts, however well that technique may work.

Comment: "s there some way to "inject" an address or replace this box with one that at least has a address bar or something equally useful?" - No;  The Explorer window in question is a legacy Win32 function and it works a specific way any alternatation to that functionality would present unknown program states

Comment: I don't really want to alter the function, just speed up getting to a folder. Although I am probably misunderstand what you are saying.

Comment: Blame the programmer for either using the Legacy file Explorer and/or using a non-standard one. The current file Explorer Window has the feature you want

Comment: Blaming doesn't help anyone :P I will of course suggest to the developers that it should be changed.